# Kibana "Discover" tab search result shows correct result while the Dashboard is not

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am running into a weird issue, I have a lot of data in ES and Kibana displays it perfectly. I have a couple of visualization which include bar-chart & pie-chart, the problem is when i click on a bar-graph of a particular object i get only a limited result but when i search for the object on the "Discover" tab i can see all the result.

The dashboard basically consists of searches which were saved earlier, so why is the behaviour occurring ?

Can someone help me on this or point me why/how is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualizations are mostly aggregations under the hood and the latter are usually limited to the top 10 results.

On the other hand, the Discover tab shows the actual records/documents stored in ES, which is why you can see many more results, usually capped at 500 by default.

Comment: Where can i tweak these settings ? Since i want to see the same result as such of "discover"

Comment: You have a `size` setting in your bar/pie chart visualizations you can tweak. Regarding the Discover tab, you can change the maximum `discover:sampleSize` in the Settings screen.

Comment: oh yes, but this is not what i am looking for. I might have misrepresented my problem, the search being performed by bar chart just shows me those objects that are specific to that bar-graph ..while on the other hand when i use "discover" it performs a full-text search and extract every occurrence of that object on that day